# android parse A&D UC-351PBT-Ci bluetooth data

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth, medical

i'm able to connect to A&D weight scale(UC-351PBT-Ci) and fetch(from bluetooth) raw data from it, but not able to parse it to get the measured weight from it. Please find the data i get from weight scale, and help me in parsing it to get the measured vale.
 e2000032800000000001002a50790026800000008000800000000000000000800000000800091ffffe80b50140000001010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

This is second data
e7000026002410000101001e0000ffffffff0d1e0014f00000000001000c0065000100060a4c00020001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

This is the third data
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

This is the fourth one
e60000020002000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

Answer (score 0):

you need to convert the data to from hex like using http://codebeautify.org/hex-string-converter

taking your "third data" the output is

`çÀ¾$¸
²
Z (A&D MedicalUC-351PBT-Ci 
   ÿþµ
D@ -($
51403001023.6.8 tag-996M   (
K@
EÀÿÿÿÿd  U@ d`

so you can see that this is probably the make and model number passed with the data.

you just have to breakdown each `byte` into its string representation

`StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
for (byte b : bytes) {
    result.append(String.format("%02X", b));
}
return result.toString();`

there will then be documentation to workout which byte represents what bit of data so assuming there would be a measurement date and the weight and the weight units etc.